# Create a link from one directory to another

Tags: macos, symlink

I have two accounts on the same Mac.

The first account has two directories `myScripts` and `downloads` that I want to use from the second account. `myScripts` is on the environment path, so I can run the scripts there from any place.

How do I create links from these directories in the first account to the second one in a way they work like they do in the first account? I understand that the second account still has a `downloads` directory by default and that the link may have to be renamed to another thing.

Also, do I have to change the permissions on the files in the first account?

Answer (score 1):

So you have user A and user B both with a `myScripts` directory and want to run scripts from the directory of user B while being logged in as user A? For this you don't need to create any link, you simply can add the directory to your path by adding the following to the shell startup file of user A:

```
export PATH="/Users/UserB/myscripts:$PATH"
```

To create a link you can run (as user A)

```
ln -s /Users/UserB/Downloads ~/Downloads-of-B
```

In both cases, you need to change permissions by logging in as user B and running

```
chmod go+rx ~/Downloads ~/myScripts
```

PS: Having said that: I find it easier to install my scripts into `/usr/local/bin` so they are available to all user accounts automatically.